# Sharepoint: SPFile.OpenBinary() , doesn't open file in binary

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I,m try to open SPFile in binary format:

SPFolder Folder = web.GetFolder(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix);

```
            foreach (SPFile File in Folder.Files)
            {

                byte[] CopyFile = File.OpenBinary();  

            }
```

but the result byte [1]=0, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted should work just fine.  Are you sure the file in question isn't just a single byte file?

Comment: FYI, You will get a 0 size file if there is a problem opening the file.